# Issue with string literal and integer constant

Tags: c++, compilation

What is it?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "str"1 << '\n';
}
```

I think that it's impossible, but gcc compiles this code (while Comeau compiler not). Why? And what about the ouput of this code?

> `str"`

And why it's not allowed when compiled as C code?

Comment: That's not valid C++ code.  And [g++ rejects it.](http://ideone.com/wgWwML)  What version (and options) were you testing with?

Comment: it can't be compiled in C due to the simple fact that there is no `cout` object in C with operator `<<`

Comment: What compiler are you using ? This is not allowed in C++ either.

Comment: @icepack I mean code like "int main(void) { "str"1; return 0; }", of course

Comment: @grhegde gcc, i already said it

Comment: @Ben Voigt http://liveworkspace.org/code/ed8b8eb313d0a14e812c9baf1fd96978

Comment: @Nikita: Sorry -- your link told me the answer, so I deleted the question you answered (what version of gcc?)  Oops!

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov It didn't compile for me with g++ or gcc

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug gcc 2.7.2 compiling C++ code as used by http://liveworkspace.org -- if you feed it `"somestring"morestuffafter`, it effectively converts it into `"somestring\"morestuffafte"` (notice that the trailing r was converted into a ").

Comment: I just tried to compile this code with my gcc 4.7.0 and it's ok

Comment: Hmm, good point -- it isn't a bug in http://liveworkspace.org -- if I feed it "str"1 as C, it complains, and as C++ it accepts it.  Regardless, it is a bug in the compiler.  :)